# Using concat() method inside React's hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering whether I can update the state’s hook value in the following way:

```
setCalcRow(calcRow.concat(displayNum.toString() + value))
```

I remember reading sometime ago that we cannot directly replace our state values in React, but at the same time `.concat()` method returns a new string as of it’s result.

Right now, my program seems to be working, visually at least, but would be a correct way to resolve my problem without violating React’s rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in using `.concat()` since as you mentioned, it returns a new array/string instead of mutating values. In fact, the method `.concat()` is used here in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) as an example show how not to mutate data.